# Storing unsigned long value in two 16bit register

Tags: java, long-integer, cpu-registers, unsigned-long-long-int

I want to store unsigned long value in two 16bit register.For example if I have long value `(-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647)` then I'm using formula like:

```
v[0] = myValue % 65536
v[1] = myValue / 65536
```

To get value from register

```
outVal = reg0 + (reg1 * 65536)
```

But how to do for unsigned long which value range is from `0 to 4,294,967,295?`

Comment: Do you know that formula works? Because it looks quite scary to me. It ought to work with unsigned operations, but signed.. I don't know, it just makes me really uncomfortable

Comment: It will give you incorrect results in the upper 16 bits when joining an originally negative value back, unless you are storing the supposedly 16-bit values in a signed 32-bit variable, yes (which is kind of against the purpose of this). And of course, it will not work at all if the `/` operator is float division, rounded to the nearest integer afterwards, and not integer division.

Comment: The values you show are min/max values of an `int`.  You want to store it in 2x16 bits = 32 bits = size of an `int`.  But you ask how to store a **long**, which is 64 bits?  So what do you want to store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commenter harold pointed out already, your formula doesn't even work correctly for negative numbers.

You should do it bitwise instead of using math to avoid surprises (and speed things up in case the compiler didn't optimize it for you already).

Splitting:

```
v[0] = myValue & 0xFFFF
v[1] = myValue >> 16    // this implicitly cuts off the lower 16 bits
                        // by shifting them away into the nirvana
```

Joining:

```
outVal = reg0 | (reg1 << 16)
```

This now applies to both signed and unsigned (provided that all your variables have the same "sign type").

---

**Legend**, in case your language (which you didn't specify) uses different operators:

`&` is bitwise AND, `|` is bitwise OR, `<<` and `>>` are bitwise shifting left/right (SHL/SHR), `0x` marks a hexadecimal literal (you could use `65536` instead of `0xFFFF`, but I think the hex literal makes it clearer where this magic number comes from).

Comment: Then my example should work as-is. See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html